# ionic cordova run android Erro

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic3

Estou com o seguinte erro ao executar o comando "ionic cordovan run android"

> Error: Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device:
>   Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1
>   Error output: error: device unauthorized. This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

As variáveis de ambiente já estão definidas, grandle instalado e etc... Não faço ideia do que esteja acontecendo, já procurei no StackOverflow e nada, o emulador do Android abre, porém o app não roda, estou utilizando o ubuntu 17.04. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar utilizar:
adb start-server
e depois adb devices (para listar os devices)

se não for exibido nenhum device você precisa verificar o seu adb e também os drives do device que você está conectando ao USB

Se a lista apareceu sem nenhum device, provavelmente seu pc/ mac não reconheceu o driver para o device,.. tente instalar o driver correto para o device, antes disso garanta que o developer Mode do aparelho está ativado, (no device acesse) Configurações gerais/ Opções de desenvolvedor/Depuração USB (ative essa opção), se após isso o seu adb ainda não reconhecer, você precisa localizar um driver ideal para seu pc reconhecer o device, normalmente o google-driver-usb que vem dentro do SDK Android já reconhece a maioria.. mas existe alguns devices que não são reconhecidos

Por exemplo o LG-K10 (tive q instalar o driver direto do site da LG)

[Download USB Drivers - Google](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)

Comment: Mas esse driver é necessário até para emular no desktop? O meu celular é um samsung  GT-l8262B, o developer mode está ativado(apesar de eu não ter tentado rodar ele no dispositivo móvel). Se ele for necessário de qualquer maneira, para emular onde eu poderia encontrar o driver e reconhece-lo? Eu precisarei conectar o celular no USB? Desculpe, estou um pouco perdido...

Comment: @MatheusFerreira, no caso do emulador o driver não é necessário, driver USB é apenas para as conexões USB, o adb deveria reconhecer o emulador, qual emulador você está utilizando?

Comment: @MatheusFerreira nos meus testes utilizava o Genymotion como emulador, nunca tive problemas pra rodar os apps;

Comment: Estou utilizando o android studio

Comment: Finalmente consegui resolver! Era só abrir o emulador antes de rodar o comando

Comment: Pelo jeito você não conseguiu mesmo conectar o device né, teve que ser via emulador, uma dica.. sempre é bom rodar o app no device antes de lançar ou nos testes antes de ir pra loja, não confie apenas no emulador, você pode ter erros que só acontecem em testes em aparelhos reais!

Vale a pena tentar deixar o seu ADB reconhecendo celulares e tablets android, tenta ver sobre os drivers USB depois e faz mais alguns testes.
eu só faço debug em aparelhos reais, em último caso eu uso um emulador!

Comment: No aparelho eu consegui porém ficou travado no inicio o app, mas acho que é porque o aparelho é muito velho, daí vou tentar em outros quando puder... Mas o meu objetivo era mais fazer rodar no emulador mesmo.

Comment: Eu testei no celular da minha namorada e funcionou... O meu que era muito velho kk Mal consigo usar ele de tão lento que é

Comment: @MatheusFerreira a então tá tudo certo, boa sorte!